# Count of certain column values in a group R

Tags: r

I have dataframe like this:

```
day gender_shopped Age
Sun 0               34
mon 1               25
sun 1               22
sun 1               44
Fri 0               23
sat 1               18
sun 0               22
```

Now i want to group by day and separate males and females shopped separately like this (here 0 means male and 1 refers to female)

```
Day   Males   Females
sun    5      2
mon    3      4
Tue    10     2
```

how to achieve this in R?

Comment: We can use `table` i.e. `table(df1[-3])`

Answer (score 1):

Making your table "test" and using table as suggested in akruns' comment:

```
library(R.utils)
test$day=decapitalize(test$day)
test.table=table(test[,-3])
colnames(test.table)=c("male","female") #assuming 0 is male, 1 is female
```

Result:

```
     gender_shopped
day   male female
fri    1      0
mon    0      1
sat    0      1
sun    2      2
```